# Chart.js v2 is there a way to draw bar chart horizontally?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a horizontal bar chart with chart.js v2. After serfing the web about two hours I have no results. Is there a way to draw a chart from left to right like this?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is part of Chart.js 2.1 now! The chart type is `horizontalBar` (with a lower case h).

```
var config = {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        ...
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gpxjohup/

---

**Original Answer**

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

Most of this code is a copy of the code for `bar` from the Chart.js library with x / y and width / height swapped. Thanks to @ZachPanzarino for helping with the axis labels!

```
Chart.defaults.HorizontalBar = {
    hover: {
        mode: "single"
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            position: 'left',
            type: "category",
            categoryPercentage: 0.8,
            barPercentage: 1,
            gridLines: { offsetGridLines: true }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            },
            position: 'bottom',
            type: "linear",
        }],
    },
};

Chart.controllers.HorizontalBar = Chart.controllers.bar.extend({
    updateElement: function updateElement(rectangle, index, reset, numBars) {

        var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
        var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);

        var xScalePoint;

        if (xScale.min < 0 && xScale.max < 0) {
            xScalePoint = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.max);
        } else if (xScale.min > 0 && xScale.max > 0) {
            xScalePoint = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.min);
        } else {
            xScalePoint = xScale.getPixelForValue(0);
        }

        Chart.helpers.extend(rectangle, {
            _chart: this.chart.chart,
            _xScale: xScale,
            _yScale: yScale,
            _datasetIndex: this.index,
            _index: index,

            _model: {
                x: reset ? xScalePoint : this.calculateBarX(index, this.index),
                y: this.calculateBarY(index, this.index),
                label: this.chart.data.labels[index],
                datasetLabel: this.getDataset().label,
                base: this.calculateBarBase(this.index, index),
                height: this.calculateBarHeight(numBars),
                backgroundColor: rectangle.custom && rectangle.custom.backgroundColor ? rectangle.custom.backgroundColor : Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(this.getDataset().backgroundColor, index, this.chart.options.elements.rectangle.backgroundColor),
                borderColor: rectangle.custom && rectangle.custom.borderColor ? rectangle.custom.borderColor : Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(this.getDataset().borderColor, index, this.chart.options.elements.rectangle.borderColor),
                borderWidth: rectangle.custom && rectangle.custom.borderWidth ? rectangle.custom.borderWidth : Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(this.getDataset().borderWidth, index, this.chart.options.elements.rectangle.borderWidth),
            },

            // override the draw and inRange functions because the one in the library needs width (we only have height)

            draw: function() {
                var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
                ctx.fillStyle = this._view.backgroundColor;
                ctx.fillRect(this._view.base, this._view.y - this._view.height / 2, this._view.x - this._view.base, this._view.height);

                ctx.strokeStyle = this._view.borderColor;
                ctx.strokeWidth = this._view.borderWidth;
                ctx.strokeRect(this._view.base, this._view.y - this._view.height / 2, this._view.x - this._view.base, this._view.height);
            },

            inRange: function (mouseX, mouseY) {
                var vm = this._view;
                var inRange = false;

                if (vm) {
                    if (vm.x < vm.base) {
                        inRange = (mouseY >= vm.y - vm.height / 2 && mouseY <= vm.y + vm.height / 2) && (mouseX >= vm.x && mouseX <= vm.base);
                    } else {
                        inRange = (mouseY >= vm.y - vm.height / 2 && mouseY <= vm.y + vm.height / 2) && (mouseX >= vm.base && mouseX <= vm.x);
                    }
                }

                return inRange;
            }
        });

        rectangle.pivot();

        // the animation progresses _view values from their current value to the _model value
        rectangle._view.x = rectangle._model.base;
    },

    calculateBarBase: function (datasetIndex, index) {
        var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
        var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);

        var base = 0;

        if (xScale.options.stacked) {
            var value = this.chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[index];

            if (value < 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < datasetIndex; i++) {
                    var negDS = this.chart.data.datasets[i];
                    if (Chart.helpers.isDatasetVisible(negDS) && negDS.xAxisID === xScale.id) {
                        base += negDS.data[index] < 0 ? negDS.data[index] : 0;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (var j = 0; j < datasetIndex; j++) {
                    var posDS = this.chart.data.datasets[j];
                    if (Chart.helpers.isDatasetVisible(posDS) && posDS.xAxisID === xScale.id) {
                        base += posDS.data[index] > 0 ? posDS.data[index] : 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            return xScale.getPixelForValue(base);
        }

        base = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.min);

        if (xScale.beginAtZero || ((xScale.min <= 0 && xScale.max >= 0) || (xScale.min >= 0 && xScale.max <= 0))) {
            base = xScale.getPixelForValue(0, 0);
        } else if (xScale.min < 0 && xScale.max < 0) {
            base = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.max);
        }

        return base;
    },

    getRuler: function () {
        var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
        var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);
        var datasetCount = this.getBarCount();

        var tickHeight = (function () {
            var min = yScale.getPixelForTick(1) - yScale.getPixelForTick(0);
            for (var i = 2; i < this.getDataset().data.length; i++) {
                min = Math.min(yScale.getPixelForTick(i) - yScale.getPixelForTick(i - 1), min);
            }
            return min;
        }).call(this);
        var categoryHeight = tickHeight * yScale.options.categoryPercentage;
        var categorySpacing = (tickHeight - (tickHeight * yScale.options.categoryPercentage)) / 2;
        var fullBarHeight = categoryHeight / datasetCount;
        var barHeight = fullBarHeight * yScale.options.barPercentage;
        var barSpacing = fullBarHeight - (fullBarHeight * yScale.options.barPercentage);

        return {
            datasetCount: datasetCount,
            tickHeight: tickHeight,
            categoryHeight: categoryHeight,
            categorySpacing: categorySpacing,
            fullBarHeight: fullBarHeight,
            barHeight: barHeight,
            barSpacing: barSpacing,
        };
    },

    calculateBarHeight: function () {
        var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);
        var ruler = this.getRuler();

        if (yScale.options.stacked) {
            return ruler.categoryHeight;
        }

        return ruler.barHeight;
    },

    calculateBarY: function (index, datasetIndex) {
        var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);
        var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
        var barIndex = this.getBarIndex(datasetIndex);

        var ruler = this.getRuler();
        var leftTick = yScale.getPixelForValue(null, index, datasetIndex, this.chart.isCombo);
        leftTick -= this.chart.isCombo ? (ruler.tickHeight / 2) : 0;

        if (yScale.options.stacked) {
            return leftTick + (ruler.categoryHeight / 2) + ruler.categorySpacing;
        }

        return leftTick +
            (ruler.barHeight / 2) +
            ruler.categorySpacing +
            (ruler.barHeight * barIndex) +
            (ruler.barSpacing / 2) +
            (ruler.barSpacing * barIndex);
    },

    calculateBarX: function (index, datasetIndex) {
        var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
        var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);

        var value = this.getDataset().data[index];

        if (xScale.options.stacked) {
            var sumPos = 0,
                sumNeg = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < datasetIndex; i++) {
                var ds = this.chart.data.datasets[i];
                if (Chart.helpers.isDatasetVisible(ds)) {
                    if (ds.data[index] < 0) {
                        sumNeg += ds.data[index] || 0;
                    } else {
                        sumPos += ds.data[index] || 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (value < 0) {
                return xScale.getPixelForValue(sumNeg + value);
            } else {
                return xScale.getPixelForValue(sumPos + value);
            }

            return xScale.getPixelForValue(value);
        }

        return xScale.getPixelForValue(value);
    }
});
```

and then

```
var config = {
  type: 'HorizontalBar',
  ...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/0y8mnma1/

Comment: As a contributor, I think you should submit this to the actual project. I know that this is one of the most requested features. https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js

Comment: @ZachPanzarino - there's a couple of places - the label positioning for the vertical category scale and the animation initialization (I assume this would also get rid of the need for the draw override) where the above answer is a bit hacky. I will update it once I understand the code better. Meanwhile I'll link this answer over at https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/73 so that folks have a temporary patch and / or something to possibly build on. The v2.0 updates were awesome by the way!! Cheers!

Comment: @ZachPanzarino - oops! just realized the question is still in its bounty period. Will link it in issues/73 once that's over.

Comment: If you add the following code to the y axis config, it will remove the need for extra labels: `gridLines: {
  offsetGridLines: true
}`

Comment: @ZachPanzarino - thanks! I updated the answer - got rid of the intialize override too with that!

Comment: +1 One problem that I have noticed is sometimes the chart will have all series at 0 until the chart is interactive with. Hovering or toggling a series gets the charts to show the correct value. So far, I have been unable to reproduce this problem outside of my own project. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: @Caleb - ah! I see there was a problem with my answer where it wouldn't render if animation was off (the same bug would also cause a problem when the canvas was resized). I have fixed it now (that also helped get rid of one of the overrides). Give it a spin. Cheers!

Comment: Works great, thanks! I had to add `var ctx = this._chart.ctx;` at the top of `draw`, but this could be because I added this into the `Chart.bundle.js` file.

Comment: @Caleb - that's needed and I've added that to the script. Thanks for catching that!The only reason it was working in the fiddle was because I happened to have the same name for the canvas context variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is a temporary hack but for now you could rotate the entire graph 90 degrees making it horizontal.

### Demo

```css
#my-chart {
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.column-1 {
  background: orange;
}

.column-2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-chart">
  <div class="column column-1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column column-2">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to do it this way, but all responsive mechanism became broken, and text are rotated too. Chart.js draws charts in canvas element, so I can't access to text fields via css and rotate it in other way

Comment: Agreed, both issues are very valid.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if it will work, but you can try. I am working on Charts.js now and found some limitations and stumbled upon this library that is a custom version of Charts.js

https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js

You dont need to change any old format you were using to pull data. 
Just replace your scripts to use :

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/pathTo/ChartNew.js"></script>
    <script src="/pathTo/shapesInChart.js"></script>
```

In shapesInChart.js files you will see customized shapes and cases. It has one for HorizontalBar and HorizontalStackedBar

Let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I edited @potatopeelings original example a bit, so now you can have offsetGridLines set to your liking and working tooltip!

```
Chart.defaults.HorizontalBar = {
  hover: {
    mode: "label"
  },
  tooltips: {
    mode: "label",
    callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
            label = [];
            for (index in tooltipItems) {          
               if (label.indexOf(tooltipItems[index].yLabel) < 0) label.push(tooltipItems[index].yLabel)
             }
             return label.join(", ");
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItem.xLabel;
        }
    }
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      position: 'left',
      type: "category",
      categoryPercentage: 0.8,
      barPercentage: 1,
      gridLines: {
            offsetGridLines: true
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      position: 'bottom',
      type: "linear",
    }],
  },
};

Chart.controllers.HorizontalBar = Chart.controllers.bar.extend({
  initialize: function(chart, datasetIndex) {
    // insert dummy labels for proper vertical positioning
    if (!datasetIndex && !chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].gridLines.offsetGridLines) {
      chart.config.data.labels.unshift('')
      chart.config.data.labels.push('')
    }

    Chart.DatasetController.prototype.initialize.call(this, chart, datasetIndex);

    this.getDataset().bar = true;
  },
  updateElement: function updateElement(rectangle, index, reset, numBars) {

    var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
    var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);

    var xScalePoint;

    if (xScale.min < 0 && xScale.max < 0) {
      xScalePoint = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.max);
    } else if (xScale.min > 0 && xScale.max > 0) {
      xScalePoint = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.min);
    } else {
      xScalePoint = xScale.getPixelForValue(0);
    }

    Chart.helpers.extend(rectangle, {
      _chart: this.chart.chart,
      _xScale: xScale,
      _yScale: yScale,
      _datasetIndex: this.index,
      _index: index,

      _model: {
        x: reset ? xScalePoint : this.calculateBarX(index, this.index),
        y: this.calculateBarY(index, this.index),
        label: this.chart.data.labels[index],
        datasetLabel: this.getDataset().label,
        base: this.calculateBarBase(this.index, index),
        height: this.calculateBarHeight(numBars),
        backgroundColor: rectangle.custom && rectangle.custom.backgroundColor ? rectangle.custom.backgroundColor : Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(this.getDataset().backgroundColor, index, this.chart.options.elements.rectangle.backgroundColor),
        borderColor: rectangle.custom && rectangle.custom.borderColor ? rectangle.custom.borderColor : Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(this.getDataset().borderColor, index, this.chart.options.elements.rectangle.borderColor),
        borderWidth: rectangle.custom && rectangle.custom.borderWidth ? rectangle.custom.borderWidth : Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault(this.getDataset().borderWidth, index, this.chart.options.elements.rectangle.borderWidth),
      },

      // override the inRange function because the one in the library needs width (we have only height)
      inRange: function(mouseX, mouseY) {
        var vm = this._view;
        var inRange = false;

        if (vm) {
          if (vm.x < vm.base) {
            inRange = (mouseY >= vm.y - vm.height / 2 && mouseY <= vm.y + vm.height / 2) && (mouseX >= vm.x && mouseX <= vm.base);
          } else {
            inRange = (mouseY >= vm.y - vm.height / 2 && mouseY <= vm.y + vm.height / 2) && (mouseX >= vm.base && mouseX <= vm.x);
          }
        }

        return inRange;
      }
    });

    rectangle.pivot();

    // the animation progresses _view values from their current value to the _model value
    rectangle._view.x = rectangle._model.base;
  },

  calculateBarBase: function(datasetIndex, index) {
    var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
    var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);

    var base = 0;

    if (xScale.options.stacked) {
      var value = this.chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[index];

      if (value < 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < datasetIndex; i++) {
          var negDS = this.chart.data.datasets[i];
          if (Chart.helpers.isDatasetVisible(negDS) && negDS.xAxisID === xScale.id) {
            base += negDS.data[index] < 0 ? negDS.data[index] : 0;
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < datasetIndex; j++) {
          var posDS = this.chart.data.datasets[j];
          if (Chart.helpers.isDatasetVisible(posDS) && posDS.xAxisID === xScale.id) {
            base += posDS.data[index] > 0 ? posDS.data[index] : 0;
          }
        }
      }

      return xScale.getPixelForValue(base);
    }

    base = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.min);

    if (xScale.beginAtZero || ((xScale.min <= 0 && xScale.max >= 0) || (xScale.min >= 0 && xScale.max <= 0))) {
      base = xScale.getPixelForValue(0, 0);
    } else if (xScale.min < 0 && xScale.max < 0) {
      base = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.max);
    }

    return base;
  },

  draw: function(ease) {
    var easingDecimal = ease || 1;
    var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.save();
    Chart.helpers.each(this.getDataset().metaData, function(rectangle, index) {
      ctx.fillStyle = rectangle._view.backgroundColor;
      ctx.fillRect(rectangle._view.base, rectangle._view.y - rectangle._view.height / 2, rectangle._view.x - rectangle._view.base, rectangle._view.height);

      ctx.strokeStyle = rectangle._view.borderColor;
      ctx.strokeWidth = rectangle._view.borderWidth;
      ctx.strokeRect(rectangle._view.base, rectangle._view.y - rectangle._view.height / 2, rectangle._view.x - rectangle._view.base, rectangle._view.height);

      rectangle.transition(easingDecimal).draw();
    }, this);
    ctx.restore();
  },

  getRuler: function() {
    var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
    var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);
    var datasetCount = this.getBarCount();

    var tickHeight = (function() {
      var min = yScale.getPixelForTick(1) - yScale.getPixelForTick(0);
      for (var i = 2; i < this.getDataset().data.length; i++) {
        min = Math.min(yScale.getPixelForTick(i) - yScale.getPixelForTick(i - 1), min);
      }
      return min;
    }).call(this);
    var categoryHeight = tickHeight * yScale.options.categoryPercentage;
    var categorySpacing = (tickHeight - (tickHeight * yScale.options.categoryPercentage)) / 2;
    var fullBarHeight = categoryHeight / datasetCount;
    var barHeight = fullBarHeight * yScale.options.barPercentage;
    var barSpacing = fullBarHeight - (fullBarHeight * yScale.options.barPercentage);

    return {
      datasetCount: datasetCount,
      tickHeight: tickHeight,
      categoryHeight: categoryHeight,
      categorySpacing: categorySpacing,
      fullBarHeight: fullBarHeight,
      barHeight: barHeight,
      barSpacing: barSpacing,
    };
  },

  calculateBarHeight: function() {
    var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);
    var ruler = this.getRuler();

    console.debug(yScale.options.stacked);
    if (yScale.options.stacked) {
      return ruler.categoryHeight;
    }

    return ruler.barHeight;
  },

  calculateBarY: function(index, datasetIndex) {
    var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);
    var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
    var barIndex = this.getBarIndex(datasetIndex);

    var ruler = this.getRuler();
    var leftTick = yScale.getPixelForValue(null, index, datasetIndex, this.chart.isCombo);
    leftTick -= this.chart.isCombo ? (ruler.tickHeight / 2) : 0;
    leftTick = (!yScale.options.gridLines.offsetGridLines) ? leftTick + (ruler.tickHeight / 2) : leftTick;

    if (yScale.options.stacked) {
      return leftTick + (ruler.categoryHeight / 2) + ruler.categorySpacing;
    }

    return leftTick + 1 +
      (ruler.barHeight / 2) +
      ruler.categorySpacing +
      (ruler.barHeight * barIndex) +
      (ruler.barSpacing / 2) +
      (ruler.barSpacing * barIndex);
  },

  calculateBarX: function(index, datasetIndex) {
    var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().xAxisID);
    var yScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getDataset().yAxisID);

    var value = this.getDataset().data[index];

    if (xScale.options.stacked) {
      var sumPos = 0,
          sumNeg = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < datasetIndex; i++) {
        var ds = this.chart.data.datasets[i];
        if (Chart.helpers.isDatasetVisible(ds)) {
          if (ds.data[index] < 0) {
            sumNeg += ds.data[index] || 0;
          } else {
            sumPos += ds.data[index] || 0;
          }
        }
      }

      if (value < 0) {
        return xScale.getPixelForValue(sumNeg + value);
      } else {
        return xScale.getPixelForValue(sumPos + value);
      }

      return xScale.getPixelForValue(value);
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/g81fzrwo/6/)

cheers
c_bb